# PHP move position of Value in Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

After a DB query I have an array with values. Now I need to put them together as in string in 4 variable but changing the position by 1 for each value and array. The count auf Values in the Array can change so I have to do this with some kind of.

For example my array looks like this

```
$array[0]="1";
$array[1]="2";
$array[2]="3";
$array[3]="4";
$array[4]="5";
```

And at the end I need 3 Strings like this:

```
$string1="1-2-3-4-5";
$string1="2-3-4-5-1";
$string1="3-4-5-1-2";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_shift` which takes of first element of array and immediately use `array_push` which adds element to the end of array.

```
$array[0]="1";
$array[1]="2";
$array[2]="3";
$array[3]="4";
$array[4]="5";

echo implode('-', $array) . '<br />';
array_push($array, array_shift($array));
echo implode('-', $array) . '<br />';
array_push($array, array_shift($array));
echo implode('-', $array) . '<br />';
array_push($array, array_shift($array));
echo implode('-', $array) . '<br />';
```